# How to disable the scientific notation when working with Perl and Excel

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx, writer

I am printing the numbers in an Excel worksheet using the Excel::Writer::XLSX module, but big integers are being printed in scientific notation.

Can this be printed as a decimal number?  For example using

```
$worksheet->write_number( 0, 0, 123456 );
$worksheet->write_number( 'A2', 2.3451 );
```

There is some limit due to which big numbers are printed in scientific notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to by @toolic, you can do something like this:

```
my $format = $workbook->add_format( );
$format->set_num_format( '#' );    
$worksheet->write_number( 'A1', 1234567890, $format );
```

That will specify "no decimal places" as your format.

See *[How to control and understand settings in the Format Cells dialog box in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264372)* for formatting reference.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned using set_num_format could be one way to help you solve this but the answer above gets rid of any decimal numbers - see [here](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JMCNAMARA/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/docs/WriteExcel.html#set_num_format()) for a list of potential styles to use... BUT ONLY if your numbers have fifteen or less significant digits. Excel limits numbers to 15 significant digits. https://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers

Luckily Excel is a bit nicer when it comes to character count! :) http://excel.tips.net/T003163_Character_Limits_for_Cells.html

If you only require the data to APPEAR as a decimal in the Excel sheet then you have the option of writing these cells as strings - don't worry they will be strings but they will look an awful lot like decimal numbers ;)

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
$WORKBOOK = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($PutTheFileHere);

$FORMAT_STRING = $WORKBOOK->addformat(num_format => '@');
$format = $FORMAT_STRING
$worksheet->write($row_num, $col_num, $field_data, $format);
```